# How to hardcode c-string in `non-const reference of type char* &` argument

Tags: c++, pointers, arguments

Why can't I compile this program?

```
void foo( const char* & str ) {
    str = "bar";
 }


 foo( "foo" ); //Compiler Error!! Why?

 const char* str = "foo";
 foo( str ); // No Erro
```

How can I hardcode my argument? like foo `( "MyString" )` ?

Comment: I've removed the C tag, since C doesn't have references.

Comment: What do you want that function to do?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes change the reference of temporary string

Comment: That doesn't really make sense in terms of C++. References cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `const char* &` is a *reference* to some pointer that exists somewhere.

Here, there is no such pointer to *refer* to.  There is a character *array*, but **creating an array does not create a pointer**.

```
foo( "foo" ); //Compiler Error!! Why?
```

Here, there are both an array `"foo"` **and** a pointer to that array.

```
const char* str = "foo";
foo( str ); // No Erro
```

**Edit from comment:**

> So why I can't write `foo( &"foo" )` ?? address of "foo" array?

Try thinking of it this way.

It's the same reason you can't write `&&&&&&"foo"` to create a `char*******`.

A `char*******` would be a pointer to memory where there's a pointer to memory where there's a pointer... (You get the idea)

C++ will not *automatically* create all these things in memory for you.

Comment: So why I can't write `foo( &"foo" )` ?? address of "foo" array?

Comment: @Khajavi What's most important to note is that `foo` was declared to demand that a pointer reside in memory somewhere.  You can't have a `const char* &` if you don't have a `char*`

Comment: @Khajavi: Because `&"foo"` gives you an R-value pointer to an array of 4 const char. Not an L-value pointer to a const char, which is what your function is expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Literals can't bind to non-const lvalue references.

Same reason you can't do this:

```
void foo(int& x) {}
// ..
foo(5);
```

You can use an rvalue reference though:

```
 void foo( const char* && str ) {
    str = "bar";
 }
```

I don't recommend this though.

Anyway, it's pointless to modify the pointer as it's a temporary and will immediately go out of scope anyways. Why are you doing this? Do you really intend `const char* const&` which will bind to both?

Comment: No, I know const reference. I need this for testing environment. so I want to test my functions in this way :)))))

Answer (score 1):

`"foo"` has type `char const[4]`, not `char const*`. An array cannot bind to a reference to a pointer, because arrays are not pointers.

Answer (score 0):

"foo" is not of type const char*

the second declaration is.

Comment: You are wrong, My pointer isn't const `const char* const & str` instead it is `const char* & str` so I can change that.

Comment: your comment doesn't makes sense